# Automatically create at shortcut to a file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small piece of code under a command button click which saves the workbook file with a new name in a new location, I am wondering if it is possible to also automatically create a shortcut to that newly saved workbook in a different location?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SelectedFNumber As String
Dim DateStr As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim StorePath As String

    DateStr = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy HH.mm")

    SelectedFNumber = Range("B4").Text

    If SelectedFNumber <> "SELECT F NUMBER" And Range("D11") > "0" Then

        StorePath = "G:\Targets\" & SelectedFNumber & "\"

        myFileName = StorePath & SelectedFNumber & " " & DateStr & ".xlsm

        If Len(Dir(StorePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir StorePath
        End If

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Else
        MsgBox "Select an F Number"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to add something like this:

```
Dim sShortcutLocation As String

sShortcutLocation = "C:\blah\workbook shortcut.lnk"

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(sShortcutLocation)
    .TargetPath = myFileName
    .Description = "Shortcut to the file"
     .Save
End With
```

changing the location to wherever you want.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I have no idea why I couldnt find an answer as simple as that anywhere else