# Create a shortcut in a folder based on excel references

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which is used to create standardised file names for the sales team within the business.  This creates the quote files (QO) and the order files (WO).  That bit i have done now, however, I now need to create a shortcut in the order file that links to the related quote file.  I have used this as my basis, but i am trying to get it to use cell references instead: [Automatically create at shortcut to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209416/automatically-create-at-shortcut-to-a-file)

Below is the code and I have highlighted where i get the error.  I have tried it with and without the "With and End With"

```
Sub CreateShortcut()

    Dim sShortcutLocation As String
    Dim strQOFolder As String, strShrtCut As String

    'place the shortcut should be created, which is in the WO folder
    sShorcutLocation = Range("C51") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C37")) & _
                        "\" & "Commercial" & "\" & Range("C39")& ".lnk" 

    strQOFolder = Range("C50") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C32")) 'path and folder name of the QO folder
    strShrtCut = CleanName(Range("C32")) 'Name of the shortcut

    'it gets the the bit below and says "Run-time error '440': Automation error
    With CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CreateShortcut(sShortcutLocation) 'believe this starts to create the shortcut in the specified location
        .TargetPath = strQOFolder 'believe this is the path of the shortcut i want?
        .Description = "Shortcut to " & strShrtCut ' believe this is what i want the name of the shortcut to be
        .Save ' save the shortcut
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The Automation Error is a generic error bubbling up from the Shell object. The general layout of your code that creates the shortcut looks right. So, I would guess there is some issues with the path names, either in `sShortcutLocation` or `strQOFolder`. You might check that your `sShortcutLocation` value ends with `.lnk`? and beyond that, check for any illegal characters in the path names?

Comment: Hi @ArcherBird, i checked both the 'sShortcutLocation' and 'strQOFolder' and they are the same as those used earlier in another sub that works fine.  Checked with the other example i attached and you are right a '.lnk' was missing from the 'sShortcutLocation'.  Now i have done this (good spot) i still get the same error.  Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: found it, the error was i had missed out a "t" the code is all in the wrong way round so will need to solve that now.

Comment: It is doing something really weird and i dont know why or how to see why? So it is saving one folder up from where it was told to, but the folder it was told to be saved in it is using for its name.  But it does link to the correct place.
So it is creating the shortcut here `Range("C51") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C37")) & "\" & "Commercial"` and naming the file based on this `Range("C39")` any ideas why?

Comment: @Steven That is what "\" & Range("C39")& ".lnk" does ? Maybe you should set strShrtCut first then use  "\" & Range("C39") & "\" & strShrtCut & ".lnk"

Comment: @CDP1802 good shout that worked! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @ArcherBird and @CDP1802 please see below working solution.  I have adding in some details so anyone like myself who is new to coding can see what i have done and what it should do.

```
Sub CreateShortcut()

    Dim sShortcutLocation As String
    Dim strQOFolder As String


    sShortcutLocation = Range("C51") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C37")) & "\" & "Commercial" & "\" & Range("C39") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C32")) & ".lnk"
    'this is the place the shortcut should be saved, with an extra level and the shortcut name i.e. to force it to save in that folder and not in the same place as that folder.
    strQOFolder = Range("C50") & "\" & CleanName(Range("C32"))
    'this is the link to where the shortcut will link to

    With CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CreateShortcut(sShortcutLocation)
    'this is creating the shortcut and the file name using the criteria set out in sShortcutLocation
        .TargetPath = strQOFolder
        'this is setting the path for where the shortcut links to
        .Save 'saves the shortcut



End With
End Sub
```

The CleanName part removes any characters not allowed in a path. Code for this is below, this isn't my own found this on here: -

```
Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")

End Function
```

Next step will be to add in a error message box. :-)  Thank you.