# Assign a hotkey to execute a .vbs file through its desktop shortcut

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have created a shortcut for my vbs file by following

> [Automatically create at shortcut to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209416/automatically-create-at-shortcut-to-a-file)

I want to assign a hotkey to this shortcut, so that I can execute the code without opening the file. Maybe something like Ctrl + Shift + P.
When I typed ***.shortcutkey*** in the editor, it changed to ***.ShortcutKey*** and I became sure that a shortcut key can be assigned to it through macro. But I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
shortcutHere = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & purpose & ".lnk"
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(shortcutHere)
    .TargetPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & purpose & ".vbs"
    .Description = "HotKey: Ctrl + Shift + P"
    .ShortcutKey '??????
    .Save
End With
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The right property is `HotKey`, not ShortcutKey. See http://jc.bellamy.free.fr/fr/vbsobj/wsobjwshshortcut.html or https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/objects-wshshortcut.html

Comment: <<When I typed .shortcutkey in the editor, it changed to .ShortcutKey and I became sure [...]>> Don't be sure, it only means that somewhere in code or in library a variable named "ShortcutKey" exists. Should you have typed ".shortcuthere" that the IDE would have capitalized the H to conform to the variable shortcutHere defined above.

Comment: Hello Vincent, Thanks for your help and guidance! It works :)

Comment: Would you like to put your comments in 'Answers' so that I can mark it with a ✓?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right property is `HotKey`, not `ShortcutKey`, so your code should look like

```
shortcutHere = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & purpose & ".lnk"
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(shortcutHere)
    .TargetPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & purpose & ".vbs"
    .Description = "HotKey: Ctrl + Shift + P"
    .HotKey = "CTRL+SHIFT+P"
    .Save
End With
```

See [Here](http://jc.bellamy.free.fr/fr/vbsobj/wsobjwshshortcut.html) or [there](http://devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/objects-wshshortcut.html) for references